# How to correctly place brackets in a CASE statement?

Tags: sql, plsql

Case Statement:

```
(CASE WHEN v_cur.order_type != 'STK' 
               AND v_cur.lot_net_cost_flag = 'Y' THEN 0 
      ELSE ( (v_cur.unit_costs_amount * v_cur.line_quantity_ordered) 
               / CASE WHEN v_cur.unit_of_measure_code = 'E' THEN 1 
                      WHEN v_cur.unit_of_measure_code = 'C' THEN 100 
                      WHEN v_cur.unit_of_measure_code = 'M' THEN 1000   
                      ELSE 1 END ) v_dt_unit_of_measure_code_val ) 
 END v_dt_cost_amount
```

Comment: Your sql statement can't work. edit your question.

Comment: What makes you think it needs brackets?

Answer (score 1):

```
case
    when v_cur.order_type != 'STK' and v_cur.lot_net_cost_flag = 'Y' then 0
    else v_cur.unit_costs_amount * v_cur.line_quantity_ordered /
        case v_cur.unit_of_measure_code
            when 'E' then 1
            when 'C' then 100
            when 'M' then 1000
            else 1
     end
end as v_dt_cost_amount
```

`CASE` syntax does not require any brackets. You only need them for mixed `OR`/`AND` logical conditions and for non-default arithmetic precedence, which you don't have in the above expression because `(x * y) / z` is the same thing as `x * y / z`.

Answer (score 0):

delete `v_dt_unit_of_measure_code_val`

```
CASE WHEN v_cur.order_type != 'STK' 
               AND v_cur.lot_net_cost_flag = 'Y' THEN 0 
     ELSE ( (v_cur.unit_costs_amount * v_cur.line_quantity_ordered) 
               / CASE WHEN v_cur.unit_of_measure_code = 'E' THEN 1 
                      WHEN v_cur.unit_of_measure_code = 'C' THEN 100 
                      WHEN v_cur.unit_of_measure_code = 'M' THEN 1000   
                      ELSE 1 END )   
 END v_dt_cost_amount
```

Comment: Actually it doesn't work. The opening bracket before the first `CASE` isn't closed after the corresponding `END`. The missing bracket is on the line above.

Comment: The edited version now has two `CASE` keywords and only one `END`.